# How to minimize a distance (more than one problem)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

**Minimizing a Distance** When we seek a minimum or maximum value of a function, it is sometimes easier to work with a simpler function instead.

**(a)** Suppose

$g(x) = \sqrt{f(x)}$

where $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$. Explain why the local minima and maxima of $f$ and $g$ occur at the same values of $x$.

**(b)** Let $g(x)$ be the distance between the point $(3, 0)$ and the point $(x, x^2)$ on the graph of the parabola $y = x^2$. Express $g$ as a function of $x$.

**(c)** Find the minimum value of the function $g$ that you found in part **(b)**. Use the principle described in part **(a)** to simplify your work.

My solutions:

**(a)** The square root of a number is always smaller than the number itself. So, in this case, whenever $f(x)$ will be the greatest, its root will also be the greatest for that value of $x$.

**(b)** $g(x) = \sqrt{(3-x)^2 + (0-x^2)^2}$

**(c)** Because we haven't reached Calculus yet in the book, I suspect that we'll use a graph to determine the result, correct? Also, how exactly will we be able to use **(a)** to simplify the results?

Comment: (a) The square root of a number is not always smaller than itself: $\sqrt{\frac14}>\frac14$, for instance.

Comment: Yeah, that struck me too. I should've mentioned that my answer was valid for $x > 1$. So, what exactly would be the correct answer?

Comment: Hint for (a): Show that $g'(x)=0$ if and only if $f(x)=0$. You can find $g'(x)$ using the chain rule.

Comment: See, again, we haven't reached Calculus yet so I was looking for a non-Calculus solution. Meanwhile, I'll try and prove it your way.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: @MXYMXY That was the entire question, nothing else is given.

Comment: @GeorgeLaw Sorry, typo: I meant show that $g'(x)=0$ if and only if $f'(x)=0$.

Comment: Okay, got it! That makes much more sense. Done! Also, any non-Calculus solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a$, note that for positive reals $a,b$, $\sqrt{a}>\sqrt{b} \Leftrightarrow a>b$.

So when the local minima of $f(x)$ occur, the corresponding square root will be at it's minimum.

For $b$, you are done.

For $c$, you need not use a graph.

Note that for $x$, $$(x^4+(3-x)^2)(1+4) \ge (x^2-2x+6) \ge 5^2$$ From Cauchy. Thus the local minima of $f(x)=x^2+(3-x)^2$ is $5$. The minimum value for $g(x)=\sqrt{f(x)}$ is $\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: How can we say that your answer for $a$ is valid for $0< x < 1$?

Comment: Also, I don't get your solution for $c$. What happened there?

Comment: He has used the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, which is the case says: $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)\geq(ac+bd)^2$. This case can be proven by expanding and rearranging $(bc-ad)^2\geq0$

Comment: @user331377 $\sqrt{a}<\sqrt{b} \Leftrightarrow a<b$ is valid for any positive $a,b$, regardless of $0<a<1$ or $0<b<1$.

Comment: @user331377 And as the user Ian Miller has said, I have used the Cauchy-Shrawrtz inequality, whose proof he provided.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't been taught that theorem yet. Where do I learn it from? Wikipedia seems a bit complicated to me.

Comment: @user331377 https://brilliant.org/wiki/cauchy-schwarz-inequality/ or https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Cauchy-Schwarz_Inequality seem pretty simple to me.